# PWA local storage gets lost when inside a browser iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, browser, local-storage, progressive-web-apps

We have an angular PWA. I am integrating with a webpageA (domainA.com) and loading our PWA(domainB.com) within an iframe. In the PWA we store some data in localStorage.

This localStorage data works when I access PWA directly, and works also when accessed through an iframe while the application (Safari or Chrome) is active.

However if I close down the browser application (swipe up) while on webpageB, when I return to webpageB, the data is lost. This applies to both Safari and Chrome on iOS.

Is there a better way to implement this? Looks like local storage in the PWA is getting cleared when the browser application closes.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Is your iframe able to communicate to the host through [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)?

Comment: Thanks for getting back Emiel. Can you explain further? We do have control over the page with the iframe in it. At the moment we are simply loading the PWA url into the iframe.

Comment: Well, if you can transfer data between the iframe and the parent page, then you could store the localStorage on domain A and transfer it to domain B when loading. For saving you'd go the other direction. In any case the data is stored on domain A.

Comment: Hmm, not ideal. It is important to note that this is a PWA. Would it help if I saved instead to indexedDB?

Comment: In my opinion it would be an easy solution as the PWA could have it's own localStorage and have it be overwritten by domain A whenever it's displayed through an iframe. Whenever the PWA saves its own state it can copy it by listening to the [`storage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event) event and send it to the parent so it actually stores it. It being a PWA shouldn't make a difference to the implementation. No idea if indexedDB would solve this.